# How to apply multiple scaling functions to the same axis?

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale, scaling

I have a parametric plot and would like to display it double logarithmic with one axis reversed.

For example how can I get two log axes for this plot:

```
ParametricPlot[{Abs[Gamma[z]], z}, {z, 1, 5}, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Reverse"}]
```

Comment: You cannot take the `Log` of the `z` axis since it includes non-positive values.

Comment: Now I can. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use your own pure function as a scaling function; you just have to provide an appropriate inverse:

```
ParametricPlot[
  {Abs[Gamma[z]], z}, {z, 1, 5},
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log10", {(-Log10[#] &), (10^-# &)}},
  Axes -> False, Frame -> True
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]