# Rotate the 2D plot

Tags: plotting

Other than `Rotate`, can we turn the plot so that it facing downward?

```
Plot[y^2 + 4, {y, -4, 4}, PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {0, 10}}, 
Axes -> {False, False}, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> None]
```

Comment: `Plot[-y^2 + 4, {y, -4, 4}, PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {0, 8}}, 
 Axes -> {False, False}, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> None]`?

Comment: Is it possible without changing the function?

Answer (score 1):

In the last days there were a few similar questions:

- [Plotting curves in 3D with different scales on different axes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131932/plotting-curves-in-3d-with-different-scales-on-different-axes)
- [How to apply multiple scaling functions to the same axis?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131889/how-to-apply-multiple-scaling-functions-to-the-same-axis)

where the answer was [`ScalingFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html). Here it is also the case via `ScalingFunctions -> {Identity, "Reverse"}`:

```
Plot[y^2 + 4, {y, -4, 4}, PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {0, 10}}, 
 Axes -> {False, False}, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> None, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {Identity, "Reverse"}]
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that my current version of Mathematica did not support `ScalingFunctions` anymore. Is there another way? @corey979